# json value null of type nsnull cannot be converted to a valid url

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I usually develop my app on an Android device. Now for some unknown reason, my app gets this error on startup when it loads some screen. I have tried to find the root of the problem, but I keep getting this error even if the screen it navigates to is completely empty.

I'm using expo so I don't have any debugger in use that can help my figure out what's wrong.

[image: error]

Comment: Create a new project.